# How to get the count of followers using Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

So here is my simple code:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

def getClient():
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXXX')
    return client

def getUserInfo(username):
    client.get_user(username=username,user_fields='public_metrics')
    return user

usr =getUserInfo('elonmusk')
```

Question is how does one now access the follower count from public_metrics?
I have read that its stored as a dict and simply trying to read is using usr.data.public_metrics won't return it, but I haven't seen anyone demonstrate the correct way to access the public_metrics data?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I spotted an error in my code. Posting the answer here so it helps others.

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

def getClient():
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXXX')
    return client

def getUserInfo(client,username):
    user = client.get_user(username=username,user_fields='public_metrics')
    return user

client = getClient()
d =getUserInfo(client,'ElonMusk')

d.data.public_metrics['followers_count']
```